# Access register values from a PicoBlaze / MicroBlaze soft processor

Tags: fpga, processor, risc

We are conducting research on the reliability of registers deployed in embedded RISC processors where the focus is to ensure the reliability of their contents during transient faults. To do this we need to be able to see register values that are held for the continuous execution of a program.

Basically, we want to write a basic program (in either assembly or some higher-level language like C) for a RISC processor and be able to store register values to a file or a computer, which can then be used as a dataset for our research, and also be able to inject faults into the register during runtime and continue storing its data.

I have been thinking about using a RISC softcore on a FPGA. I have access to a range of Xilinx FPGAs and Vivado, so I am considering using the PicoBlaze or MicroBlaze softcores for this task.

So my questions for anyone that is familiar with the Blaze softcores:

1. Is there a way of writing a register value to a file using these Blaze softcores?
2. Can you go inside the Blaze IP blocks and add logic to allow the register value to be changed at various times while in operation? Can you add logic inside the Blaze component?

Comment: How would you distinguish instability of the register contents from instability of the added logic that extracts the register contents? How can you guarantee stable and reliable execution of the extraction after the fault, independently of the stability of the normal execution pipeline? This is a fairly tricky problem that comes up quite frequently in fault injection side-channel research.

Comment: @Polynomial I have planned to have a few sample programs to gather the register values from to create different datasets. This way as I add the additional logic to the architecture, I can run the same program and verify that the added logic from fault injection doesn't influence the registers behavior during normal operation. The extraction of the data under faulty conditions on the other hand will probably be the hard part.

Comment: Not a bad approach, but you will have to content with probabilistic behaviour from the glitches as a confounding variable due to tolerances in your glitching setup and variations in the environment (both inside and outside the IC). I'm also unsure that you could specifically attribute fault injection susceptibility to a soft core implementation itself, rather than the specific FPGA hardware you chose or properties of the bitstream the synthesis tool happened to generate (a version update might invalidate all of your findings!)

Comment: Typically when assessing an MCU, MPU, SoC, secure element, or other IC the attack target is the exact physical part that will be used in production. For ASICs this is easy, because nothing changes - you try the attack on a half dozen chips to make sure you can reliably induce a fault on a product rather than just a single chip (manufacturing tolerances matter!), but once you've done that you know it will work everywhere - but with a soft core there isn't a single concrete low-level implementation at the physical layer, so it's less meaningful to target fault injection attacks there.

Comment: @Polynomial I know what you are saying is very true. I thought an FPGA softcore would be the best solution. Can you think of any other way of obtaining data from registers?

Comment: If you chose to instead target a microprocessor IC, you could utilise JTAG as a fairly reliable mechanism for gaining access to register state. If the processor completely crashes to the point where JTAG is non-functional, there's probably not a lot interesting about that fault state. Since the debug interface is _mostly_ discrete and constructed from static elements, it's about as low level and non-destructive of data as you can get without getting into decap and microprobe territory. You'd want to minimise the JTAG operations for reading the registers, though.

Comment: You'd still need to use your sampling approach across programs, and you'd need to repeat the test on a number of different ICs (ideally from separate batches) to eliminate behaviours that only occur on a single IC or batch due to a manufacturing variance, but the approach would at least likely yield usable results without needing to delve into direct silicon analysis.

Comment: One option for reading registers might be to use the configuration subsystem.  I know a couple of people who spent quite a bit of time figuring out how to read back the current state in an attempt to dynamically swap out a portion of the design, sort of like how an OS can switch between processes dynamically.  This can also potentially enable you to detect bit flips in the configuration data itself.  The hard part is probably to get a consistent read while the CPU is running; you may need to gate the clock so you can read the state with the clock stopped.

Comment: So maybe a better solution is to use a MCU development board instead of a softcore on an FPGA. So for example, is there a relatively reliable and easy way using a MCU to read the program counter data every clock cycle? I'm assuming there are no built-in functions to ever need to do that, but if I could store the program counter value in a variable and send it to a PC via serial communication would be ideal. Thinking it must be possible with assembly code at least? With ARM the program counter is a general purpose register as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Polynomial I think David wants to deliberately and deterministically inject faults rather than just glitching the chip? Obviously glitches don't transfer very well to completely different styles of chips, and glitching an FPGA is likely to corrupt the FPGA fabric and not just the microprocessor register contents.